# translate xlop-doc.fr.tex

Tags: compilation-error

Good night I use Debian 10 and I have installed texlive-full. I'm trying to translate the file 'xlop-doc-fr.tex' (https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/xlop) to PT_BR and I come across the following errors:
! LaTeX Error: File `fvrb-ex.sty 'not found.
Type X to quit or  to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

I already researched here on the site and found some examples that also did not work. I await help from already thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The package `fvrb-ex.sty` used to be part of the `fancyvrb` bundle, but it has been renamed some time between 2017 and 2018 to `fancyvrb-ex.sty`.

Change the corresponding line in `manual.sty`.